# IIS Rewrites and Redirects

Tags: tomcat, iis, url-rewriting, redirect

Lets assume I have an already deployed IIS web application that is accessible via https://test.com:2345/testpage/index.html.

This web-application already makes ajax requests to get relevant data, display content etc. from a proxy application deployed in IIS at the URL https://test.com:2345/proxy/test.asmx.

Everything works fine here, but now lets say I have deployed my proxy application in tomcat and so the proxy application URL is now changed to https://test.com:2346/proxy/test. Only the port is changed here, domain remains same for now.

I do not want to change the existing code of my web application in IIS but when the web application makes a request to the proxy application, I want to either redirect/rewrite the request URL from https://test.com:2345 to https://test.com:2346. Is this possible directly from IIS?

I have read about IIS URL rewrites and redirects, but I have not quite been able to understand this, can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You can Interface your Apache Tomcat using the IIS. This way the IIS would take requests as is on port 2345. Requests to `/proxy` context path would be forwarded to
[The AJP Connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/ajp.html)
of Apache Tomcat behind the scene. Tomcat Port 2346 would not even need to be accessible from outside:

```
Requests /proxy/* -> IIS port 2345 -> AJP port 8009 -> Processing by Tomcat
```

If your `workers.properties` looks like this:

```
worker.list=tomcat01
worker.tomcat01.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat01.host=localhost
worker.tomcat01.port=8009
```

You would map the URL pattern `/proxy/*` to your tomcat in your `uriworkermap.properties`:

```
/proxy/*=tomcat01
```

Beware that for beginners this is a long way to go and you have to learn / try & error a lot. Any typo in a config or anything not perfectly following the documentations linked below will result in arbitrary and absolutly **non self explaning error messages**.

This is the general Tomcat Connector configuration overview:

[The Apache Tomcat Connectors: mod_jk, ISAPI redirector, NSAPI redirector](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/index.html)

The concrete HOW TO for IIS:

[ISAPI redirector for Micrsoft IIS HowTo](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html)

The IIS connector reference guide:

[The Apache Tomcat Connectors - Reference Guide](https://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/iis.html)

Good luck, have fun!